# How do I get the URL to change to the correct/current page with jQuery Mobile and Reponse.Redirect?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, jquery-mobile, response.redirect

I have an Inbox Message page that contains a list of messages sent to a person by another user.  Clicking on this message will open up a thread of messages between these two people with the ability to reply to a message sent by the original sender (this page is MessageContent.aspx).  This goes to another page (called MessageReply.aspx) that allows the person replying to create a new message in a textarea control with a button to "Send Message" which adds that reply to the end of the list of messages in the previous thread and does a Response.Redirect to go back to that page.

Overall I have everything working how I want to, but the only issue now is that the URL never changes when going from the MessageReply page back to the MessageDetail (one containing all the thread messages) page.

For example, the MessageDetail URL is "http://mysite/MessageContent.aspx?ThreadId=24".
Replying to a message goes to this URL: "http://mysite/MessageReply.aspx?message=26".
When the message gets sent to the Detail page and redirects to it, the URL still shows "http://mysite/MessageReply.aspx?message=26"

Here is the code I have in the MessageDetail to open the Reply page (using a HyperLink control):

```
string url = SPContext.Current.Site.ServerRelativeUrl + "/MessageReply.aspx";
                HyperLink ReplyHyperLink = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("MessageReply");
                ReplyHyperLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "external");
                ReplyHyperLink.NavigateUrl = QueryStringUtils.AppendParameter(url, MessageQueryString, item.Id);
```

Here is the code I have for the MessageReply SendMesage button:

```
// Send the message
            var contentEditor = (HtmlTextArea)this.FindControl("ContentEditor");
            client.SendMessageReply(_messageId.Value, SubjectTextBox.Text, contentEditor.InnerText);

            Message message = client.Read(_messageId.Value);

            // Redirect back to the MessageContent page
            string url = SPContext.Current.Site.ServerRelativeUrl + "/MessageContent.aspx";
            string pageUrl = QueryStringUtils.AppendParameter(url, ThreadIdQueryString, message.ThreadId);
            Response.Redirect(pageUrl);
```

Anyone have any idea how to get the URL to change when it sends the message reply?  Everything else is working fine.  I greatly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

The most simple route for this would be turn off ajax on the form itself that is being submitted.  All the assets required to build the next page should already be in cache so when your next page is bounced with the redirect, provided you've crafted each page to stand alone, the load times will not be any higher.

To turn off Ajax on a form that's giving you trouble...

```
<form ... ... data-ajax="false">
```

Then, just be sure that the next page is constructed as a standard JQM page that could be called directly with a GET request and everything should be fine.